# PHP array and JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema, phpdoc

Many times I have had this scenario in php where I have a data structure but it is hard to work with because PHP doc cannot handle it.

```
<?php
/** @var (??) $contact */
$contact = array(
  "firstName" => "John",
  "lastName" => "doe",
  "age" => 26,
  "address" => array(
    "streetAddress" => "naist street",
    "city" => "Nara",
    "postalCode" => "630-0192"
  ),
  "phoneNumbers": [
    array(
      "type"  : "mobile",
      "number": "333 444 5566"
    ), array(
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "333 222 1100"
    )
  ]
}
```

Perhaps PHPDoc can handle it and I just don't know how. But at least **JSON Schema** sounds like a great choice for documenting structures like that, and JSON objects always can be mapped 1:1 to php arrays, so here is the question:

Is there a way to document a data structure, in an IDE like PhpStorm, in a way that I would get correct type help when typing something like this?:

```
$contact["phoneNumbers"][0]["type"]
```

It is ok if the solution is not with JSON Schema, PHP doc would be enough if it could go so deep in structure.

Oh, and creating a `class Contact {}` and a `class PhoneNumber {}` is not feasible because the structure is not as simple as the one I mentioned here, and it would be an overkill to write all those classes just for type hinting.

Thanks in advance for your help!

JSON Schema: https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html